# how to display content of two dimensional string array in listview under two columns?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

how to display content of two dimensional string array in listview under two columns?

```
     string[][] arrStr = new string[10][];

     ListViewItem itm = new ListViewItem();
     itm = new ListViewItem(arrStr);
     listView1.Items.Add(itm);
```

This is not working. Please suggest.

Comment: Please replace lines after arrStr declaration  with the below   and let me know if that works then i will add that as answer        foreach (var item in arrStr)
            {
                ListViewItem itm = new ListViewItem(item);
                listView1.Items.Add(itm);
            }

Comment: Good to know that its worked.. good luck .. added the comments as answer please mark as answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please replace lines after arrStr declaration with the below lines

```
foreach (var item in arrStr){ 
ListViewItem itm = new ListViewItem(item);
listView1.Items.Add(itm);}
```

Comment: it worked as in it did compile without error, however the data is not yet populating in listview. I have set listview1.view = details.